# If someone opens a Word document from a USB drive but does not save it to the computer, can I access the file's contents after the drive is removed?

Tags: security, data-recovery, usb-flash-drive, microsoft-word-2016

If someone opens a Word document from USB flash drive but does not save it to the computer, can I access the file's contents
after the drive has been removed? If so, how?

I already tried data recovery and automatic office recovery and I didn't find it. My Office version is 2016.

Comment: AFAIK: I'm afraid NO

Comment: Are you trying to recover a document? Or are you worried about someone else accessing a document? It’s not clear from your question what exactly your concern is.

Comment: @Toto, ...it's more a "maybe" than a "no". A forensic memory dump may well find that document still in RAM if the system has plenty of unused memory and has been idle since. That's part of why Giacomo's question above is so pertinent: if the intent of the question is "how much care do I need to take to reliably protect myself from a document being read after I removed the device that contained it?", that's a question with a longer answer.

Comment: (Mind, having "tried data recovery and automatic Office recovery" itself creates memory churn and reduces the chances of finding the content in a snapshot will be successful).

Comment: ...I haven't reviewed it in detail, but at least the introductory parts of the Medium post [Windows memory forensics using open source tools](https://aditya-pratap9557.medium.com/windows-memory-forensics-using-open-source-tools-3ec09930732e) looks credible and on-point, as someone with nonzero experience in the matter.

Comment: From a more security relevant perspective: I suppose at least fragments of the file may be found in the swap file (perhaps only after an "unclean" power off?), or if the computer hibernated, in the hibernation RAM image.

Comment: There are a few different ways this question can be relevant. One of them is "My USB drive is no longer readable, any chance I can recover from the hard drive?" And for that, I must tell you the advice I've been telling people since the days of floppy disks (yes, I am that old) **Never rely on removable media as the primary storage for any important document.** USB drives are *generally* quite reliable. But like floppy disks, they can be lost, stepped on, stolen, etc. and are generally less reliable, overall, than internal hard drives (whether magnetic/mechanical or solid-state).

Comment: Did you already close Word after removing the usb drive? Please [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: there can be many of indirect ways parts or all of the document leak out... meta data (such as what filename was opened when) aren't the only infos that can be persistently recorded, for example, microsoft/google/etc sends snippets "anonymously" to its servers for various "customer improvement" purposes. So ram and swap are not the only places you might be shocked to find parts or all of the document, it can be 3rd party apps too (such as antivirus).

Answer (score 16):

Do this first, before restarting Word.
Depending on the settings, and what happened, search for `*.doc`, `*.docx`, `*.dot`, and `*.wbk` files in the following locations:

- `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word`
- `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles`
- `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp`
- `C:\Windows\Temp`

Then try “File -> Manage Document -> Files Tab -> Document Management -> Recover unsaved documents.”

If Word was set to autosave periodically, a backup can be found in the defined directory. “File -> Options -> Save -> Save AutoRecover information every X minutes.” The directory is given in the same place.

Comment: Use this answer only after mine - entering Word can cause it to cleanup orphaned drafts, so try to find and save the drafts before entering Word.

Comment: (partly @harrymc) I'd be tempted to copy all candidate files from both methods/all locations to removable storage, and open them on another machine (or perhaps in LibreOffice, still working on the copies)

Answer (score 13):

If you have edited the files, even in a small way, and exited Word
brutally by killing the Word process, or just took the USB out thus
letting Word abort, then you might still have a draft of the document
in your TEMP folder (the folder is pointed-to by the environment variable
`TEMP`).

However, if you have exited Word in the normal way, all draft copies of
the document were removed, and it's just too late.

As a last effort, look into the Recycle Bin for a file that has a
similar file-name to the edited files, usually with a destroyed
first character. But that's all you can do.

Comment: _all draft copies of the document were removed_... so file recovery using Recuva etc is possible?

Comment: Recuva and similar programs can find deleted files on the disk, or sometimes fragments of files, but may or may not find the original file-name. You may need to locate the file by its attributes such as location and size. You'll never know if you don't try, but avoid writing to the disk while trying to recover files.

Comment: I don't see why it would appear in the recycle bin. You're describing what a file recovery tool will show from an actually deleted file. Word never recycles any of its temporary files, it deletes them directly.